# Error at xsl:result-document: Invalid relative URI syntax: URI is not absolute

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XSLT code. I'm using version 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="Lakes">
        <xsl:for-each select="Lake">
            <xsl:result-document href="file{id}.xml">
                <document>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>
                </document>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The error in NetBeans is:

> Error at xsl:result-document on line 5 of dividir.xsl:   Invalid
>   relative URI syntax: URI is not absolute

Comment: Does NetBeans support XSLT 2.0 out of the box? Do you know which XSLT 2.0 processor it uses? Do you run the XSLT with some Java code?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of the `id` element in your input XML.  If it has a `:` in it, it may be confusing the XSLT processor into thinking you're trying to specify an absolute file path in the `@href` to `xsl:result-document`.